# Strange metadata return for Dynamics multiselect picklist

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, picklist, dynamics-crm-webapi

When I attempt to retrieve metadata for field information from Dynamics using the call: `EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='lead')/Attributes/` I receive all the information I required except for my multiselect picklist.

For this object the AttributeType is "Virtual" and there is no LocalizedLabels for the Description or DisplayName.

Is this just a bug in the metadata or is there a unique call I need to do for multiselects?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the topic "**Querying EntityMetadata attributes**" and "**Retrieving attributes**" in below given URL, It will helpful for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx